# jump condition for ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Given $(\beta u')' = f(x)$, $u(-1) = 0, u(1) = 1$ where $\beta = 1+ H(x)$ and $H$ is the Heaviside function.
For 
$$f= 0, \quad f=H, \quad f=\delta,\quad f=\delta'$$
I would like to find the jump condition at $x=0$ and the solution $u$.

This is from an old exam, and I have not seen this type of problem before. I am not sure what is the jump condition, so I tried by solving with integration and here is my attempt.

- For $f=0$, then we know $\beta u' =c$ thus 
  $$u'=c/\beta = \begin{cases}
  c \quad & x\leq 0 \\
  c/2 \quad & x>0
  \end{cases}$$
  we just simply integrate
  $$u(x) = \begin{cases}
  cx+d \quad & x\leq 0 \\
  cx/2+d \quad & x>0
  \end{cases}$$
  we want $u(-1) = 0$, thus $-c+d = 0$, and $u(1) = 1$, thus $c/2+d = 1$.
- For $f=H$, we know 
  $$\beta u' =\begin{cases} c \quad & x\leq 0\\
  c+x \quad & x >0
  \end{cases}$$ 
  which implies 
  $$u' =\begin{cases} c \quad & x\leq 0\\
  \frac{c+x}{2} \quad & x >0
  \end{cases}$$ 
  and again we simply integrate and find the integration constant $c$ and $d$.
- $f= \delta$, we know $\beta u' = H + c$ so 
  $$u' =\begin{cases} c \quad & x\leq 0\\
  \frac{c+1}{2} \quad & x >0
  \end{cases}$$ 
  and again we find integration constant $c,d$.
- $f= \delta'$, we know $\beta u' = \delta + c$, so 
  $$u' =\begin{cases} \delta + c \quad & x\leq 0\\
  \frac{\delta + c}{2} \quad & x >0
  \end{cases}$$

$$u =\begin{cases} H + cx + d \quad & x\leq 0\\
\frac{H + cx}{2} + d \quad & x >0
\end{cases}$$ 
and we find $c,d$ again with boundary conditions.

Are these correct? 
Thanks!

Comment: $\beta$ is constant ?
If $f(x)=1+H(x)$, why are you giving other expressions of $f$ ?
You only have to deal with : $f=0, f=H, f=\delta, f=\delta'$ ?
In which class of functions are you looking for $u$ ?

Comment: Sorry,  I meant $\beta = 1+H(x)$. I also had the question of which solution space I should use. I think the solutions belong to Sobolev space except the last one.